# How to show the numbers in indian format in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-v1

I am having an input type of number when the user types a number it should be displayed in indian format that is

```
Example:  500000 should be displayed as 50,000
```

Without using javascript how could i use the indian format in the html itself.

I have already used the filters to show the values in indian format which works well for viewing the data but i would like to do the same during input also but when i tried using the same filter in the model it doesn;t show anything.

Html:

```
<input ng-if="vm.farmer.type === 'Advance'"
        type="number" maxlength="9" placeholder="{{'advamount_message' | translate}}" step=".01"
        ng-model="vm.advance.amount_out" ng-change="vm.fillStarted()"
        next-focus id="field1"
        field-to-validate="yes"
        field-value="{{vm.advance.amount_out}}" field-validation-type="num" field-name="{{'vamount_message' | translate}}">
```

Filter used for view:

```
.filter('INR', function () {
return function (input) {
  if (!isNaN(input)) {
    //var currencySymbol = '₹';
    /*var result = input.toString().split('.');
    var lastThree = result[0].substring(result[0].length - 3);
    var otherNumbers = result[0].substring(0, result[0].length - 3);
    if (otherNumbers !== '') {
      lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
    }
    var output = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ',') + lastThree;
    // var output = otherNumbers.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d)+\d$)/g, ',') + lastThree;
    if (result.length > 1) {
      output += '.' + result[1];
    }
    return output;*/
    var negative = input < 0;
    var str = negative ? String(-input) : String(input);
    var arr = [];
    var i = str.indexOf('.');
    if (i === -1) {
      i = str.length;
    } else {
      for (var j = str.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
        arr.push(str[j]);
      }
      arr.push('.');
    }
    i--;
    for (var n = 0; i >= 0; i--, n++) {
      if (n > 2 && (n % 2 === 1)) {
        arr.push(',');
      }
      arr.push(str[i]);
    }
    if (negative) {
      arr.push('-');
    }
    return arr.reverse().join('');
  }
};
```

During view:

```
{{vm.farmer.balance | INR}}
```

Comment: Have you tried just `{{vm.farmer.balance | number}}`? I think this inbuilt filter does what you want anyway, without building your own.

Comment: I'm sure there is a better solution but here is what you can try: `Number("100000").toLocaleString('en-IN');` --> `1,00,000`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey how could i use this in html itself instead of doing it in javascript

Comment: @KarlReid Is it possible to use filter in ngModel ?

Comment: Consider `(500000).toLocaleString('hi')` gives `"५,००,०००"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this filter

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
        {{price | INR}}
    </div>

    <script src="../lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.filter('INR', function () {
            return function (input) {
                var length = input.length;
                if(input.length < 3)
                {
                    return input;
                }
                else {
                    var input = input.split(''); //convert it to string and split it into the chars
                    var output = input[length - 3] + input[length - 2] + input[length - 1];
                    var j = 2;
                    for(i=input.length;i--;i>1)
                    {

                        if(j>1)
                        {
                            output = ',' + output;
                            j = 0;
                        }
                        else {

                        }
                        if (i != 0)
                            {
                        output = input[i - 1] + output;
                        j++;
                        }
                    }
                    return output;
                }
            }
        });
        app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.price = '4665987565';
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use this :-
In HTML Template Binding
{{ currency_expression | currency : symbol : fractionSize}}

In JavaScript
$filter('currency')(amount, symbol, fractionSize)

<script>
  angular.module('currencyExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.amount = 1234.56;
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input type="number" ng-model="amount" aria-label="amount"> <br>
  default currency symbol ($): <span id="currency-default">{{amount | currency}}</span><br>
  custom currency identifier (USD$): <span id="currency-custom">{{amount | currency:"USD$"}}</span><br>
  no fractions (0): <span id="currency-no-fractions">{{amount | currency:"USD$":0}}</span>
</div>
```